# tilde mu open sets in generalized topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I found this article "on tilde mu open sets in generalized topological spaces" and from the article these sets are defined as follows.
Let (X, µ) be a generalized topological space. A subset A of X is said to be a µ˜-open set, if there exists a µ-open set U of X such that U ⊆ A ⊆ csµ
(U). The set of all µ˜-open sets is denoted by µ˜O(X). The example given is Let X = {a, b, c} and μ = {{}, {a}}. Then ˜μ-open sets are {{}, X, {a}, {a, b}, {a, c}}.
My problem is I couldn't figure how they got these sets because as I have tried it based on the definition, my results are different and I end up just getting the same sets as the mu open sets. Where could I have gone wrong?

Comment: What is csµ(U)? Closure? Also -- what is a "generalized topological space"? There are a lot of generalizations of topology in the literature. Your example seems to just involve a plain old topological space.

Comment: the intersection of mu semi closed sets (the smallest mu semi closed set containing U)

Comment: And what, exactly, is a semi-closed set?

Comment: a class μ subset of  exp(X) is  a generalized topology (briefly, GT) if the emptyset is in  μ and the arbitrary union of elements
of μ belongs to μ

Comment: A subset A of a generalized topological space (X, μ) is said to be μ-semi-open if A is a subset of  cμ(iμ(A)) (closure of the interior of A). The complement of mu semi open is mu semi closed

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the semi-closure of the empty set is the empty set, and the semi-closure of {a} is X. Thus a set A satisfies U ⊆ A ⊆ csµ(U) for some open U if and only if A is empty or it contains a. This is exactly the sets in {{}, X, {a}, {a, b}, {a, c}}.

Comment: why is X the semi closure of {a}?

Comment: It is the *only* semi-closed set containing {a}. What else could it be?

Comment: i think my problem is my interpretation of the definition of semi closure because I don't have X as the only semi closed set containing {a}. please enlighten me

Comment: The mu-semi-open sets are *also* the sets in {{}, X, {a}, {a, b}, {a, c}}. Their complements are thus the mu-semi-closed. X is the only one of the resulting complements that contains a. What is one of the supersets of {a} (other than X) that you think is semi-closed?

Comment: my problem is my mu semi open sets are all of the P(X), thus the mu semi closed are also the sets in P(X). First thing I did was to get the interior (the largest open set contained in the set) then get the closure of the interior.All of the subsets of X are subsets of the closure of the interior making all of them semi open sets. I know there is something wrong in my process I just couldn't trace it yet.

Comment: The interior of any set is either the empty set (which is its own closure) or {a} -- which has X as its closure. I have no idea why you would think that e.g. {b,c} is semiopen. The closure of its interior is empty.

Comment: yeah I finally got it. thanks